# How to resample a batch of rasters using OGR/GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, ogr

I'm looking for a function similar to GRASS r.resample. I have a folder full of TIF files and want to reduce their resolution ("scale them down") to reduce file size.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your best bet would appear to be gdalwarp, which is documented over [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html). It's trivially easily scriptable, but the details would depend on your operating system. In Windows, you'd do something like:

```
for %i in (*.tif) do gdalwarp -ts 1600 0 -r cubic -co "TFW=YES" %i %~ni_small.tif
```

which *should* reduce the input files to 1600 pixels wide, saving the file with the original name appended with "small". This is seriously untested, ymmv. Besides, you're probably using Linux - if so, post back, and someone can help there. Ditto if you're looking for a Python solution.

Edited: added parameter to create ESRI world file. Note that this solution doesn't specify the output format, so it's a GeoTiff by default