# Batch convert jpeg2000 to GeoTIFF?

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff, batch

I need to convert approximately 3500 jpeg2000 4-band NAIP images to GeoTiff format without mosaicing.  I have access to ENVI, ERDAS and Arc 10--is there an efficient way to batch convert these files to GeoTIFF while maintaining quality and band integrity?

Comment: Shame you don't have access to Photoshop - a few clicks and the batch created and only the time to process is a restriction.

Answer (score 9):

I think that all of listed by you software allow to execute batch converting in some way.

**ArcGIS**

I can explain how is it possible to perform in ArcGIS.

1. Converting of one raster JPEG2000 -> GeoTiff can be done using tool [Raster To Other Format (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_To_Other_Format/001200000032000000/). Don't forget to setup appropriate [raster storage settings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_raster_storage_settings/001w00000024000000/) in [Environment variables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/001w/001w0000003s000000.htm#GUID-A6109C0F-D946-4E8F-BEB6-A3028B6192B3) when running this tool.
2. Running this tool in a batch mode can be done using ArcGIS [batch processing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000w000000) function. Again don't forget about environment settings in order to get desirable results.

**Erdas**

I remember that in Erdas it is also possible to execute commands in batch mode. But it was some time ago and right now I don't have access to this software. Take a look at this [document](http://www.erdas.com/Libraries/Support_Workflows/Batch_Processing_-_Multiple_Files_Single_Command.sflb.ashx) if you prefer to use Erdas.

**Open-source solution**

Also can recommend trying to use opensource solution: [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/). Which can be executed in a batch mode by OS tools (in Win - bat, powershell for example).

Take a look at command [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) - this one you need for your task.

Example:

`gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co TILED=YES input.jp2 result.tif`

Set correct (for your case) [creation options](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html) in `-co` parameter.

How to run it in a batch mode you can figure from [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25702/batch-script-converting-and-resampling-orthophotos) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/how-to-resample-a-batch-of-rasters-using-ogr-gdal) available topics.

Comment: My GDAL install (1.11 on Ubuntu) doesn't include JP2, what's your recommendation? There is quite a bit of choice, not sure which is the best and easiest to install.

Comment: @Thomas I upgraded to GDAL 2 that supports JP2. I installed it with homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Use LizardTech's (free) GeoViewer's Tools->Export.
It is an order of magnitude faster than gdal_dtranslate.
Although this is not a batch process, I did find dlls in the directory where the .exe is located that may enable writing your own export utility.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a bit tardy, given the age of the question, but I'll share a process that worked well for me.

I used the USGS free conversion tools described at this site: https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/tools/rasterconversion/Convert_JP2_Data_to_GeoTIFF_with_GDAL.html

The tricky part was recognizing that I needed to install GDAL, and sorting out the right version for my antique WinVista box was a bit challenging - but once I got GDAL installed, the USGS scripts worked fine as a drag and drop approach from within the Windows Explorer interface.