# Converting JPEG2000/MrSid files to GeoTIFF using GDAL

Tags: geoserver, gdal-translate, raster-conversion, jpeg-2000, mrsid

This question is related to one previously asked: [Batch convert jpeg2000 to GeoTIFF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26040/batch-convert-jpeg2000-to-geotiff)

We certainly need to batch convert some JPEG2000 files to GeoTIFF; the problem is, it doesn't seem to work. We don't have ready access to ArcGIS, so the GDAL solution discussed previously is what we need to work with -- but here's the rub:

The JPEG2000 files in question originated in the MrSID format, and apparently have supporting metadata that make them work properly. When we convert a file with gdal_translate, there are two problems.

First, a GeoTIFF converted in this way doesn't seem to be properly optimized for anything. Loading the file as a layer in QGIS (to test if the output is a valid raster), it takes lengthy minutes to render -- versus a GeoTIFF exported by the [LizardTech GeoViewer](https://www.lizardtech.com/support/geoviewer-pro), specifically designed for this sort of thing, which takes only a second or two to render (even though both files are about 4 GB in size). It would be ideal to be able to batch-convert the files using GeoViewer but there does not seem to be a way to do that.

Second, the GeoTIFF converted by gdal_translate is not able to be served at all by GeoServer. It allows the creation of a layer using the image but then serves only a blank layer. It is unclear why this is happening. Presumably whatever MrSID metadata is present and necessary in the original JPEG2000 is not being carried over to the GeoTIFF.

Any advice on why this conversion is not working, or how to do it correctly?

Comment: All tiffs are not alike as you will notice if you read carefully the manual page of GDAL geotiff driver https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html. Create tiled, perhaps compressed tiffs and add overviews with gdaladdo. Seach this site for exact commands, I am sure that similar questions have old answers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Here you seem to be asking at least two unmarked questions.  One about "Loading the file as a layer in QGIS" and another about GeoServer.

Comment: I am only using QGIS to test if the thing is working or not (i.e. if gdal_translate is outputting a valid raster). The ultimate goal is to serve the raster in GeoServer. The real question is not about either, but about converting the raster. I am being as specific as I know how to be.

Comment: That is to say, the statements about QGIS and GeoServer are just to point out that the GeoTIFF I am getting has problems and I don't understand why. The question I am asking is about gdal_translate.

Comment: Read the raster parts of https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gs-steroids-sgiannecfoss4g20130103 and https://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-on-steroids-foss4g-2015. Why you have problems is because you have now a large striped tiff file without overviews.

Comment: Thanks, @user30184. Adding overviews with gdaladdo fixed the problem and allowed the TIFFs to work in GeoServer.