# FWTools ogr2ogr in Python

Tags: python, gdal, fwtools

I am trying to convert MapINFO tabs to ESRI Shapefiles using FW Tools. I downloaded the tools and can run the FW Tools Shell and convert no problem:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" E:\CABWorking\MapINFO2SHP\SHP\LincsBoundary.shp E:\CABWorking\MapINFO2SHP\MapINFOData\Lincolnshire.tab
```

In the shell you can type python and use the shell as a python interpreter. Awesome, but I need this to work as I want to convert a ton of MapINFO files at once.

My problem is: I can't figure out how to get the following code to work in a python environment. I've been searching all morning and just have no clue. Any help would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: The FW Tools binaries are several years old. If you are on Windows try OSGeo4W instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resample a batch of rasters using OGR/GDAL?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/how-to-resample-a-batch-of-rasters-using-ogr-gdal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python the os module provides a quick and dirty way to run a command line argument such as the one you posted as part of a larger script as outlined in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)

```
import os
command = "ogr2ogr -f \"ESRI Shapefile\" E:\\CABWorking\\MapINFO2SHP\\SHP\\LincsBoundary.shp E:\\CABWorking\\MapINFO2SHP\\MapINFOData\\Lincolnshire.tab"
os.system(command)
```

Note the use of backslashes to escape characters such as " and \ in the command string.

As I said, this is quick and dirty, the Pythonic way to do this is to use the [Subprocess library](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) which provides the same functionality but in a more stable framework, and with some more features:

```
import os
command = "ogr2ogr -f \"ESRI Shapefile\" E:\\CABWorking\\MapINFO2SHP\\SHP\\LincsBoundary.shp E:\\CABWorking\\MapINFO2SHP\\MapINFOData\\Lincolnshire.tab"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000) 
#the third command suppresses the opening of a new window for each process
#and can be removed if this is not the desired outcome
process.wait() #waits for one process to complete before launching another one
```

---

I used this answer to solve my issue. Thanks a ton @sgrieve. The final code ended up being:

```
import os, glob
inputDir = raw_input("==> ") # Had to have this code compatible with 2.3.4
outputDir = raw_input("==> ") # So that meant no easy file dialog boxes
TabFiles = glob.glob(str(inputDir) + '/*.tab')
for TabFile in TabFiles:
    TabFileName = TabFile[(TabFile.rfind("\\"))+1:(TabFile.rfind("."))]
    command = 'ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ' + outputDir + "/" + TabFileName + '.shp ' + TabFile
    os.system(command)
```

I'd then open the FWTools Shell, enter python and call the script with:

```
execfile("script")
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but when run it doesn't work. I think it's because python is trying to run the command in CMD as oppose to the FW Tools Shell. Maybe I need to bring the shell into CMD as well?

Comment: Yes, you will need to import the FW tools shell into the command prompt. The process is outlined here http://pythoncentral.org/how-to-install-python-2-7-on-windows-7-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/ for importing python to the command shell, but the process should be the same for FW Tools.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Took me a little bit to get it going, but it now runs pretty smoothly thanks to your help! I'll paste the code in your answer.

Comment: It is an old post but escaping the double quote allowed me to execute ogr2ogr from python or php. After setting up the command, from python I used subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ,) and from php exec($command);, I used the ogr2ogr from http://www.gisinternals.com.

Answer (score 2):

use this code with entering its folder with your command line:

```
for %f in (*.tab) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" %~new.shp %f
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: This seems great. Where about's would I specify the input and output directory?