# Clip and copy files to same directory structure using OGR/GDAL with Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, osgeo

We need to clip all our data (many TB) by a new boundary and save it while maintaining the same data structure. I want to use OGR/GDAL as the data is in shp/tab/kml/geoTif/ecw etc.

I can find the file and create the data structure in python but need to use ogr/gdal to then clip the file and save it to the new directory in the same projection and file type as the input. I have written the process to do this using arcpy but that doesn't work for tab and ecw, so I would prefer to go opensource but am new to this...

So the python is as follows --

```
import os, glob, sys, shutil, datetime, subprocess
top = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Offline Dataset\MapInfo_Tables\Property Information' # Source directory for all files to check and process
#top = os.getcwd()
RootOutput = r'C:\junk' # Directory to copy/move files to
RootDirDelete='C:\\' #repatative name of root file path to remove from new directory name
clip_polygon='c:\junk\boundary.shp'
filecount=0
successcount=0
errorcount=0

print "Working in: "+ top

list =[]
f = open(RootOutput+'\\Success_LOG.txt', 'a')
f.write("Log of files Succesfully processed. RESULT of process run @:"+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
f.close()


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for directory in dirs:
        currentPath=os.path.join(root,directory)
        os.chdir(currentPath)
        #arcpy.env.workspace = currentPath
        print os.getcwd()
        lstFCs = glob.glob('*.*')
        print lstFCs
        for fc in lstFCs:
            OutPutDir=RootOutput+"\\"+str(os.getcwd()).strip(RootDirDelete)
            filecount=filecount+1
            if OutPutDir.endswith(".gdb"):
                print "File in GDB...SKIPPING"
            else:
                try:
                    os.makedirs(OutPutDir)
                    print "Created: "+OutPutDir
                except:
                    #pass
                    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

##                try:
                fcIn=currentPath+"\\"+fc
                fcOut=OutPutDir+"\\"+fc
                ext=fc[fc.find('.')+1:]
                if ext=='shp':
                    subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clip_polygon, fcOut, fcIn], shell=True)
                    successcount=successcount+1
                    print "Data clipped: "+fcIn+" to " +fcOut
                else:
                    print 'extension not shp'
```

---

I need

- ogr clip function to clip data by clip_polygon for vector, raster and elevation

  -in arcpy it is like

  #arcpy.Clip_analysis(outPath+'\'+outFileN+'.shp', clip_features, outPath+'\'+outFileN+AOI+'.shp', xy_tolerance)

  -in ogr2ogr as a process I guess the following would work ([Error when using gdal/ogr and python to clip a "shp" file by a "shp"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62584/error-when-using-gdal-ogr-and-python-to-clip-a-shp-file-by-a-shp))

  #subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clipping_shp, output_shp, input_shp], shell=True)
- projection should be same as input (usually EPSG 28355 or 4283)

UPDATE: I ran the above process and it gives the following errors, the subprocess when run independently reports a 1 but no file is written...

```
[Dbg]>>> fcIn
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MapInfo\\Offline Dataset\\MapInfo_Tables\\Property Information\\shp\\TRC_DCDB.shp'
[Dbg]>>> fcOut
'C:\\junk\\Program Files (x86)\\MapInfo\\Offline Dataset\\MapInfo_Tables\\Property Information\\shp\\TRC_DCDB.shp'
[Dbg]>>> clip_polygon
'c:\\junk\\boundary.shp'
[Dbg]>>> subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clip_polygon, fcOut, fcIn], shell=True)
1
[Dbg]>>> 
[Dbg]>>> subprocess.check_call(['gdalinfo', fcIn], shell=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '['gdalinfo', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MapInfo\\Offline Dataset\\MapInfo_Tables\\Property Information\\shp\\TRC_DCDB.shp']' returned non-zero exit status 1
[Dbg]>>>
```

UPDATED

```
        if ext=='shp':
            subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clip_polygon, fcOut,  fcIn])
```

gives me the following error.

```
>>> 
Working in: C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Offline Dataset\MapInfo_Tables\Property Information
C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Offline Dataset\MapInfo_Tables\Property Information\shp
['TRC_DCDB.dbf', 'TRC_DCDB.prj', 'TRC_DCDB.sbn', 'TRC_DCDB.sbx', 'TRC_DCDB.shp', 'TRC_DCDB.shx', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.dbf', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.prj', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.sbn', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.sbx', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.shp', 'TRC_DCDB_Raw.shx']
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
extension not shp
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
extension not shp
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
extension not shp
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
extension not shp
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.WindowsError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\junk\Clip_And_Copy_Files.py", line 45, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clip_polygon, fcOut,  fcIn])
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

From [FWTools ogr2ogr in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33629/fwtools-ogr2ogr-in-python)

I tried

```
>>> command = 'ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" ' + fcIn + fcOut
>>> os.system
<built-in function system>
>>> os.system(command)
1
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\junk'
>>> fcOut
'C:\\junk\\Program Files (x86)\\MapInfo\\Offline Dataset\\MapInfo_Tables\\Property Information\\shp\\TRC_DCDB.shp'
>>> fcIn
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MapInfo\\Offline Dataset\\MapInfo_Tables\\Property Information\\shp\\TRC_DCDB.shp'
>>>
```

but again I get no output..

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't use shell=True (especially with lists, see [Getting output from Python script in Python tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095733/getting-output-from-python-script-in-python-tests/9096104#9096104)

```
import subprocess
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".shp"):
           fileok=  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(subdir,file))      
           subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", "clip.shp",  "res2.shp", fileok])
```

or

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".shp"):
         fileok=  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(subdir,file))    
         command = ["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", "clip.shp",  "res3.shp", fileok]     
         subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

works

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. How do I automatically deal with non-shp files? i.e I want it to work on all files that it can read such as tab, grid, ecw, tif etc.

Comment: thanks but I am still having issues...see updated question.

Comment: see  if file.endswith(".shp") and adapt

Comment: point is that even the clip on the shp doesn't seem to work. The next issue will be dealing with the different file types individually and finding something similar in OGR as arcpy.List.