# Cropping a Shapefile into a Rectangular Box with Python pyshp

Tags: python, shapefile, extents, pyshp

Using ['pyshp'](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) I am hoping to reduce the set of US highway shapefiles to only those in Puerto Rico.  The idea is very easy since I only need those pieces which fit into the window.

```
>> import shapefile
>> sf = shapefile.Reader("roadl_usa") 
>> len(sf.records())

193504
```

Not familiar with the writing object but hoping it's easy since I am not building from scratch.  How do I select only those records in the bounding box `[-67.5, -65.0]` and `[17.8, 18.6]` and write a new shapefile?

What is the output like?  I am wondering if `.shx`, `.txt`, `.dbs` also get exported and what they mean.

---

This script almost works except it leads to `IndexError: list index out of range` - maybe this is because I am deleting things in the process of iterating?

```
import shapefile
e = shapefile.Editor("roadl_usa")

prbbox = [-67.5, 17.8,-65.0, 18.6]

L = len(e.shapes())    
for t in range(L):
    if f( e.shape(t).bbox, prbbox) > 0:
        e.delete(t)

e.save('pr-roads')
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-Python solution

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" pr-roads.shp roadl_usa.shp -clipsrc -67.5  17.8 -65.1  18.6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ogr2ogr modules modules, you can actually run the line given by  John Mangual in Python.

This link have same helpful answers regarding to that. 
[Using ogr2ogr to convert GML to shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39080/how-do-i-use-ogr2ogr-to-convert-a-gml-to-shapefile-in-python)

Also you can run line with os module as in this link

[FWTools ogr2ogr in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33629/fwtools-ogr2ogr-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is very interesting.  The Editor class in PyShp is still a work in progress but I'll look into it further.

Here's some code I just tested using your bounding box on a US roads shapefile.  PyShp does export the SHX and the DBF files.  Those are the minimum requirements of a shapefile.  The SHP file is the geometry, the SHX file is a simple record index for the geometry, and the DBF file contains the attributes.

```
import shapefile

# Create a reader instance
r = shapefile.Reader("roadl_usa") 

# Create a writer instance
w = shapefile.Writer(r.shapeType)

# Copy the database fields to the writer
w.fields = list(r.fields)

# Our selection box
xmin = -67.5
xmax = -65.0
ymin = 17.8
ymax = 18.6

for road in r.iterShapeRecords():
    # Shape geometry, Database Attributes
    geom = road.shape
    rec = road.record
    # Get the bounding box of the shape
    sxmin, symin, sxmax, symax = geom.bbox
    if sxmin <  xmin: continue
    elif sxmax > xmax: continue
    elif symin < ymin: continue
    elif symax > ymax: continue
    # Road is inside our selection box.
    # Add it to the new shapefile
    w._shapes.append(geom)
    w.records.append(rec)

# Save the new shapefile! (.shp, .shx, .dbf)
w.save("Puerto_Rico_Roads")
```